Add Authentication to Docusaurus site for a SaaS product
I am creating documentation for a SaaS product that is accessed via a login page. I want my documentation site to be behind the login of the SaaS product. So anyone visiting the doc site url will be shown the SaaS product login page before they can visit the doc site. Also once the use logs in, the session should be continued for other documentation pages as well. Is there a way to achieve this is Docusaurus? We are not using any external authentication tool such as firebase, oauth, AWS cognito, etc.
My SaaS product is www.example.com and the doc site is www.example.com/documentation.
A user needs to login to access the SaaS product hosted on www.example.com. But www.example.com/documentation is currently not behind that login. I want the user to be presented with the www.example.com login page if the user lands on the documentation URL. Basically I want my doc site to be behind login/authentication of the SaaS product.

Have a look here: https://github.com/levino/protected-docs-example
